# clock_t not compiling with MPLAB XC8

Tags: c

hopefully this is a simple question with a simple answer. Code is written in C.
I am using MPLAB IDE v1.60 with XC8 compiler but it is not recognizing "clock_t". I have MPLAB set for device PIC18F6520.
error messages i get when i try to build are as follows;

```
ClockTimer.c:16: error: undefined identifier "clock_t"   
ClockTimer.c:16: error: expression syntax   
ClockTimer.c:18: error: expression syntax   
ClockTimer.c:19: error: undefined identifier "stop"  
ClockTimer.c:19: error: undefined identifier "start"
```

The code is below;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    // Execuatable code
    clock_t stop = clock();
    double elapsed = (double)(stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time elapsed in ms: %f", elapsed);

}
```

any ideas why this is not compiling?
thanks
Mark

Comment: Read the compiler documentation, it might be that the library simply doesn't support those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since clock_t is often just an alias for unsigned long, try compiling with

`unsigned long start =  clock();`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have found problems in that the IDE cannot find the file. Try copying the file from the library and placing it directly in in your project folder, then include as "time.h" and your problem should be fixed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A look in the XC8 User Guide indicates the `time()` and `clock()` functions are not supplied by the xc8 compiler and must be supplied by the user.